# Can the extension of a veracrypt file be changed without damaging the file?

Tags: pdf, privacy, truecrypt, veracrypt, extension

is this possible? so I can change the file back to its original extension and use it and when I am done using it, I change the extension to maybe a .mp4 or .pdf something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Editing filename doesn't affect file contents.

Renaming file and changing it back is undetectable.

Be careful to not accidentally alter the file when other programs try to open it as a different format though.

Comment: Not the file name now but like adding an extension behind the file, like .dat .ini , would this affect the veracrypt file?

Comment: @juanpablo.onepablo Extension is simply a part of the filename. It was treated specially in early DOS days, but it's not anymore since DOS 5 or 6 I think. It's just a part of the filename that we've agreed to use to indicate file type for our convenience. Nothing special about it as long as filesystem and OS are concerned.

Comment: So lets say I name a veracrypt file with the .ini extension, is there a way to check the file structure to determine if it is indeed a .ini file or if it is being disguised as a .ini file?

Comment: @juanpablo.onepablo Well, a legit INI file probably wouldn't be a few (hundreds) GB in size. It would also be a text file. Formats that won't fail these checks will be suspicious because they won't match known file signatures and data entropy will be unusually high (a property of good encryption). [This article](https://www.raedts.biz/forensics/detecting-truecrypt-veracrypt-volumes/) is quite good.

Comment: Going by the methods listed , is there anyway to bypass the forensic steps outlined in the article you posted so that it seems like the file isn't an encrypted volume?

Comment: @juanpablo.onepablo I can't think of any. Almost any file format has some characteristic signatures: magic numbers, headers, structure etc. VeraCrypt's container is different, because quality encryption looks like random data, and it seems that it's designed to _not_ have any particularly obvious structure. That makes it distinctive, although not obviously identifiable.